# finding the sum of the sreies, using java

Tags: java

the question is to find the sum of this series

[series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKoLA.png)

i used this code to solve it , but im not quite sure the logic is correct.
the noofterms is how many terms are going to be added
and x is the number that will be assigned to the variable.
does the logic seem correct?

```
public static double sumOfSeries(double x, int noofterms){
    double evennumbers=1;
    double oddnumbers=1;
    double result=1;


    // since the power of x starts from 1 , we start i from 1 and increment by 2
    for (int i=1; i<noofterms; i+=2 ){
        // we reset starting numbers so we start from them everytime
        evennumbers = 1;
        oddnumbers = 1;

        // everytime the number increases by 2 when it is smaller than i+1
        // ex when its equal to 2 , j = 3 , j+1 = 4 so it increments by 2
        // when its 4 , j = 5 , j+ 1 = 6 , it increments
        for (int j=2; j<=i+1; j+=2){
            // multiply by increments of 2
            evennumbers= evennumbers * j;
        }

        // it starts from 1 and increments by 2 so it goes like 1,3,5
        for (int z=1; z<=i; z+=2){
            oddnumbers = oddnumbers * z;
        }

        result*=((Math.pow(x, (double)i)) / (double)i) + (oddnumbers/evennumbers);




    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i mean does the logic seem correct or not?

Comment: Why not test it yourself? assume a set of inputs, find outputs of your program for that and see if they match?

Comment: #iSmellAUnitTest :P

Comment: FYI you should be able to delete your own question. The link is in the bottom left, underneath the tags.

Comment: it is not letting me

Answer (score 2):

You can do it better. Note that numerators and denominators form two sequences, so you can keep previous terms to efficiently make computations, this will look like this :

```
long even = 1;
long odd = 1;
double result = x;

for(long i = 1; i < noofterms; i++)
{
    even *= 2 * i;
    odd *= 2 * i - 1;

    double oper = Math.pow(x, (double)(2 * i + 1)) / (double)(2 * i + 1);
    result += (double)even / (double)odd * oper;
}
```

You can improve by using logarithms because even and odd will grow very fast and will lead to overflows :

```
double even = 0.0;
double odd = 0.0;
double result = x;
double logx = Math.log(x);

for(long i = 1; i < noofterms; i++)
{
    even += Math.log((double)(2 * i));
    odd += Math.log((double)(2 * i - 1));

    double oper = logx * (2 * i + 1) - Math.log((double)(2 * i + 1));
    result += Math.exp(even - odd + oper);
}
```

EDIT:  only one sequence could also be computed : `p *= (double)(2*i)/(2*i-1)`. Then the log trick is not useful.

Comment: what do you mean by p *= (double)(2*i)/(2*i-1) ?

Comment: In each iteration compute p and then : result += p*Math.pow(x,2*i+1)/(2*i+1)... It's the same idea as before but simpler.

Comment: You can even compute Math.pow(x, ...) iteratively... That will be more efficient.